# Merging dictionaries with single entries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this:

```
[[{'end': 3250741247,
   'ip_range': '193.194.64.0 - 193.194.95.255',
   'start': 3250733056},
  {'descr': 'PROVIDER'},
  {'descr': 'Algerian Academic Research Network'},
  {'country': 'DZ'}],
 [{'end': 3273187327,
   'ip_range': '195.24.192.0 - 195.24.223.255',
   'start': 3273179136},
  {'descr': 'Data communication and international'},
  {'descr': 'telecommunication of Cameroon'},
  {'country': 'CM'}]]
```

Is there a way to combine the 'descr' keys to hold the two (or more) values under the same key.

I want something like this:

```
[[{'end': 3250741247,
   'ip_range': '193.194.64.0 - 193.194.95.255',
   'start': 3250733056},
  {'descr': 'PROVIDER','Algerian Academic Research Network'},
  {'country': 'DZ'}],
 [{'end': 3273187327,
   'ip_range': '195.24.192.0 - 195.24.223.255',
   'start': 3273179136},
  {'descr': 'Data communication and international','telecommunication of Cameroon'},
  {'country': 'CM'}]]
```

is this possible? if so, how?

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
for block in result:
    description = {}
    for dic in block:
        if dic.__contains__('descr'):
            description = {i:j for i in dic.keys() for j in zip(dic.values(),description.values())}
    block.append(description)
```

Comment: Show expected result

Comment: I've edited it :)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What did you try, and what was the result? You'll have to go through the list of dictionaries, accumulating values with common keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst = [[{'end': 3250741247,
   'ip_range': '193.194.64.0 - 193.194.95.255',
   'start': 3250733056},
  {'descr': 'PROVIDER'},
  {'descr': 'Algerian Academic Research Network'},
  {'country': 'DZ'}],
 [{'end': 3273187327,
   'ip_range': '195.24.192.0 - 195.24.223.255',
   'start': 3273179136},
  {'descr': 'Data communication and international'},
  {'descr': 'telecommunication of Cameroon'},
  {'country': 'CM'}]]
# container for output list
new_list = []

# Loop through all the nested lists
for ls in lst:
    # container to capture the value of the 'descr' key
    descrval = []
    # container to capture the index of the dict in nested list
    descridx = []
    # now we loop through all the dicts in nested lists
    for i, dct in enumerate(ls):
        # if the 'descr' key exists, we capture it
        if 'descr' in dct.keys():
            descrval.append(dct['descr'])  # value
            descidx.append(i)  # nested list index
    # remove all existing dicts
    for i in sorted(descridx, ascending=False):
        ls.pop(i)
    # pops back the joint dict for the 'descr' key
    ls.append({'descr':descrval})
    # pushes the new list to the output list
    new_list.append(ls)
```

Note: I constructed this solely within the textbox and did not run any tests on it. Please check for correctness personally.